# Pooled standard deviation of two correlated variables

Tags: variance, effect-size, pooling

I'm trying to calculate an effect size index where I need to pool 2 standard deviations calculated from correlated variables (pre-post treatment scores). Using the standard formula:

$$
\sigma^2_{pooled} = \frac{\sigma_x^2 (n_x - 1) + \sigma_y^2 (n_y - 1)}{n_x + n_y - 2}
$$

I'm not taking into account the correlation between $x$ and $y$. Is there a method to consider the correlation?

Comment: Are $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma_y^2$ (I prefer to use $\sigma^2$ to $\sigma$ to represent variance, which looks to be so) in your expression sample variances or theoretical variances? It seems to be the sample variance, because it makes little sense to defined pooled (sample) variance if theoretical variances of the two samples are different.

Comment: thank @Zhanxiong I have fixed the notation. yes, they are theoretical variances. The difference could be in terms of sample size. Furthermore, I would like to pool two variances of two variables that are correlated

Comment: It's unusual to see this "pooled theoretical variance" definition in my experience.  Could you provide a reference which used this notation and explained the motivation?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just examining the post-pre differences?  Indeed, the possibility of having different numbers of each type of score raises questions, such as why do these numbers differ?  What is your sample design?  What statistical test are you performing?  All these are relevant to defining suitable effect sizes.